CSS mix-blend-mode: difference - color issue on Safari
On Safari 16.6 im getting strange colors when using mix-blend-mode: difference
CSS
body{
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
    font-size:50vh;
    line-height: 1;
    color:rgb(0,0,255);
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}
.m1{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    color:rgb(255,255,0);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

HTML
<body>
    HELLO
    <div class="m1">WORLD</div>
</body>

Safari Screenshot:

On Firefox, Chrome and mobile Safari it looks as expected:


Can't reproduce on Safari 16.5 and 17.3. Not sure if this only occurs on 16.6.
